# What is the best way to use this in prototype method

Tags: javascript

It is comfortable to create **self = this** variable. In all methods we always can use **self**, and don't worry about method context - some times **this** in method not we expected.
But in prototype method we can't use this hint;

Look at the example (jQuery needed onle to show the question)

```
var myClass = function () {
    this.propery = 'someData';

    var self = this;

    this.method = function () {
        console.log(self.propery);
    }
}

myClass.prototype.method2 = function () {
    // want to use self here
    console.log(this);
}


var my = new myClass();

var eventBus = $({});
eventBus.bind('onMyEvent', my.method);
eventBus.bind('onMyEvent', my.method2);

eventBus.trigger('onMyEvent');
```

What is the best way to declare the class with possibility to use **self** in prototype methods?

Comment: No, you just cannot use `self` in prototype methods. Don't make them prototype methods if you need `self`. Or even better, `bind` the methods to the instance when you use it as an event handler.

Comment: There is no need of 'self' in the code you shown. Use "bind" while registering the event handler.
If you need to do `self=this` in future please try using `var self = this`
So it will not pollute global space.

Comment: @Bergi thank you. Don't know how to mark your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `self`, just need to set the value of `this` by [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the object to the function:

```
var MyClass = function () {
  this.property = 'someData';
  this.method = function () {
    console.log(this.property);
  };
};

MyClass.prototype.method2 = function () {
  console.log(this);
};

var my = new MyClass();

var eventBus = $({});
eventBus.bind('onMyEvent', my.method.bind(my)); // bind
eventBus.bind('onMyEvent', my.method2.bind(my)); // bind

eventBus.trigger('onMyEvent');
```

Comment: `.bind` is an ES5 thing, so it won't work on earlier browsers. For earlier, you can use `.apply()` in a wrapper, or if jquery (the example looks like it uses jquery) then `$.proxy(fn,this)`. I can edit the answer if you want

Comment: I wouldn't invest much time with support for ancient browsers, I'd include the [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim), use the code and call it a day.

Comment: No need to use any shims at all, as jQuery already comes with `bind` implementation.

Comment: I need a "like" button here; I would "like" your last comment. But I upvoted the answer...